# areAllItemsEnabled method

Tags: java, android

Searched through and found this explanation for `areAllItemsEnabled()`:  Indicates whether all the items in this adapter are enabled.
I saw this method in some Google project so it might be useful and I don't even know why.
The question is when to use it?

My question was when exactly use it at practice and whether there are benefits of using this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()):

> ```
> public boolean areAllItemsEnabled ()
> ```
>
> Indicates whether all the items in this adapter
>   are enabled. If the value returned by this method changes over time,
>   there is no guarantee it will take effect. If true, it means all items
>   are selectable and clickable (there is no separator.)
>
> Returns True if all items are enabled, false otherwise.

Use this when you need to know whether all items are selectable and clickable

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot that I can click inside method in documetation.